# In Python, using beautiful soup- how do I get the text of a XML tag that contains a hyphen

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

I'm trying to get the text content on tag 'Event-id' in the XML, but hyphen is not recognizing as an element on the file, I know script is working well because if a replace the hyphen for a underscore in the XML and run the script it works, anybody knows which could be the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eventsUpdate xmlns="http://nateng.com/xsd/NETworks">
    <fullEventsUpdate xmlns="">
        <fullEventUpdate xmlns="">
            <event-reference xmlns="">
                <event-id xmlns="">24425412</event-id>
                <event-update xmlns="">34</event-update>
            </event-reference>
        </fullEventUpdate>
        <fullEventUpdate xmlns="">
            <event-reference xmlns="">
                <event-id xmlns="">24342548</event-id>
                <event-update xmlns="">34</event-update>
            </event-reference>
        </fullEventUpdate>
    </fullEventsUpdate>
</eventsUpdate> 



from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

dir_path = '20211006085201.xml'

file = open(dir_path, encoding='UTF-8')
contents = file.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml')

events = soup.find_all('fullEventUpdate')


print(' \n-------', len(events), 'events calculated on ', dir_path, '--------\n')

idi = soup.find_all('event-reference')

for x in range(0, len(events)):
    idText = (idi[x].event-id.get_text())
    print(idText)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are dealing with namespaced xml, and for that type of document, you should use css selectors instead:

```
events = soup.select('fullEventUpdate')
for event in events:
    print(event.select_one('event-id').text)
```

Output:

```
24425412
24342548
```

More generally, in dealing with xml documents, you are probably better off using something which supports xpath (like lxml or ElementTree).

Answer (score 0):

For XML parsing idiomatic approach is to use xpath selectors.

In python this can be easily achieved with [`parsel`](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel) package which is similar to `beautifulsoup` but built on top of `lxml` for full xpath support:

```py
body = ...
from parsel import Selector
selector = Selector(body)
for event in sel.xpath("//event-reference"):
    print(event.xpath('event-id/text()').get())
```

results in:

```
24425412
24342548
```

Answer (score 0):

**Without** any external lib (Just ElementTree)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eventsUpdate xmlns="http://nateng.com/xsd/NETworks">
    <fullEventsUpdate xmlns="">
        <fullEventUpdate xmlns="">
            <event-reference xmlns="">
                <event-id xmlns="">24425412</event-id>
                <event-update xmlns="">34</event-update>
            </event-reference>
        </fullEventUpdate>
        <fullEventUpdate xmlns="">
            <event-reference xmlns="">
                <event-id xmlns="">24342548</event-id>
                <event-update xmlns="">34</event-update>
            </event-reference>
        </fullEventUpdate>
    </fullEventsUpdate>
</eventsUpdate> '''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
ids = [e.text for e in root.findall('.//event-id')]
print(ids)
```

output

```
['24425412', '24342548']
```